# Error running code taking from Gymnasium tutorial

Tags: python, openai-gym

I would like to run the following code using PyCharm IDE

```
import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2", render_mode="human")
observation, info = env.reset(seed=42)
for _ in range(1000):
   action = env.action_space.sample()  # this is where you would insert your policy
   observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)

   if terminated or truncated:
      observation, info = env.reset()

env.close()
```

I got the code from [here](https://gymnasium.farama.org/). I installed "Gymnasium" in my computer using "pip install gymnasium". The Python version I am using is "Python 3.11.5".

ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
Failed to build box2d-py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" - What will be the solution?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering an error while trying to install the "box2d-py" package, which is a dependency for the "gymnasium" package. The error message suggests that there was a problem building the "box2d-py" package.

1. Make sure you have the necessary build tools installed on your system. On Linux, you can install them using the package manager. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. On macOS, you can install the Xcode Command Line Tools by running `xcode-select --install`.
2. Try installing the "box2d-py" package separately using the following command:

   ```
   pip install box2d-py
   ```

   If the installation fails, you may need to install additional dependencies specific to your operating system. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run `sudo apt-get install swig` before retrying the installation.
3. Once the "box2d-py" package is successfully installed, you can try installing the "gymnasium" package again using the following command:

   ```
   pip install gymnasium
   ```

Comment: It did not work.